# PHP Wildcard Usage and Replacing (may need REGEX)

Tags: php, regex, wildcard, str-replace

Sorry for a silly question,

but I have a variable (say `$my_data`) in which data is stored, where many times URL like `href="http://PAGE_PATH/the_page_name"` has been used.

I want that all `href="http://PAGE_PATH/the_page_name"` where `the_page_name` varies every single time gets replaced with `onclick="jsonData('the_page_name', 'something')"`

But I am stuck as `the_page_name` are different every time.

I think some `str_replace` like functions may be used? I don't know.

Help Appreciated!

**EDIT**

I have an example that I used previously but here `the_page_name` did not matter:

```
$base_paths = array("http://PAGE_PATH");
$web_paths  = array(link_url()."page");
$content = str_replace($base_paths,$web_paths, $this->input->post('pg_content'));
```

Comment: are all of your paths in the root? or do some of them have sub-folder or more nested levels?

Comment: I'd think `str_replace($my_data . '"', '" onclick="jsonData(\'the_page_name\', \'something\')"', $string)`. This also assumes `$my_data"` will never exist outside the elements. It'd be cleaner/more accurate to use a parser.

Comment: All my domain names are dynamic as they are made under codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

I think a regex is your solution

[a link here](https://regex101.com/r/ZAzkoy/1)

**Explanation**

> /href="https?:/{2}\S*/([^\r\n\t\f ]+)"/g

**href="http**     matches the characters href="http literally (case sensitive)

**s?**     matches the character s literally (case sensitive)

**?**     Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

**:**     matches the character : literally (case sensitive)

**/{2}**     matches the character / literally (case sensitive)

**{2}**     Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times

**\S***     matches any non-whitespace character

*****     Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

**/**     matches the character / literally (case sensitive)

1st Capturing Group ([^\r\n\t\f ]+)

Match a single character not present in the list below [^\r\n\t\f ]+

**+**     Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

**\**     matches the character \ literally (case sensitive)

**r**     matches the character r literally (case sensitive)

**\n**     matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)

**\t**     matches a tab character (ASCII 9)

**\f**     matches a form-feed character (ASCII 12)

**  **     matches the character [space]  literally (case sensitive)

**"**     matches the character " literally (case sensitive)

```
<?php

$mydata = 'Sorry for a silly question, but I have a variable (say $my_data) in
           which data is stored, where many times URL like
           href="http://PAGE_PATH/the_page_name1" has been used.

I want that all href="http://PAGE_PATH/the_page_name2" where the_page_name2 
varies every single time gets replaced with onclick="jsonData(\'the_page_name\', \'something\')"
href="http://PAGE_PATH/the_diff_name"
href="http://PAGE_PATH/the_other_name"
But I am stuck as the_page_name href="http://PAGE_PATH/another_name" are different every time.

I think some str_replace like functions may be used? I dont know.

Help Appreciated!';


$pattern = '/href="https?\:\/{2}\S*\/([^\\r\n\t\f ]+)"/i';
$replacement ='onclick="jsonData(\'\1\',\'something\')"';

echo "BEFORE<br/>$mydata<hr/>AFTER<br/>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $mydata );
?>
```

Comment: Was this solution helpful?